# regular expression in string.replace with a callback function

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

```
 function helpLinkConvert(str, p1, offset, s)  {  
      return "<a href=\"look.php?word="
               +encodeURIComponent(p1)+"\">"+p1+"</a>";
     }

var message = "(look: this) is a (look: stackoverflow) question";
message = message .replace(/\(look: (.{1,80})\)/, helpLinkConvert);
```

This is what I want to do,

**Before:**

(look: this) is a (look: stackoverflow) question.

**After:**

[this](http://www.mywebsite.com/look.php?word=this) is a  [stackoverflow](http://www.mywebsite.com/look.php?word=stackoverflow) question

---

When there is only one matched string, it's working but in other cases It's not working properly,

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the global `g` modifier , and a non-greedy match so the regular expression finds all matches:

`/\(look: (.{1,80}?)\)/g`

In your code:

```
function helpLinkConvert(str, p1, offset, s) {  
    return "<a href=\"look.php?word="+encodeURIComponent(p1)+"\">"+p1+"</a>";
}

var message = "(look: this) is a (look: stackoverflow) question";
message = message.replace(/\(look: (.{1,80}?)\)/g, helpLinkConvert);
```

Outputs:

`"<a href="look.php?word=this">this</a> is a <a href="look.php?word=stackoverflow">stackoverflow</a> question"`

Comment: Or better yet, instead of: `.{1,80}?` use: `[^)]{1,80}`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `g` flag:

```
message .replace(/\(look: (.{1,80})\)/g, helpLinkConvert);
```

The `g` (stands for "global") will match against *all* occurrences of the pattern on this string, instead of just the first one.